# depth of field varies with distance?

Tags: aperture, depth-of-field

I am wondering if there is a difference in the depth of field if I stand near the subject or far from it with the same aperture (like f1.4) ?

Thanks for responses

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is depth of field and bokeh influenced by distance to the subject?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8451/is-depth-of-field-and-bokeh-influenced-by-distance-to-the-subject)