# Which one is better for outdoor portraits Nikon DX NIKKOR 55-200MM F/4-5.6G VRII or 35mm f1.8?

Tags: portrait, focal-length, prime, bokeh

Which one will give me more intense background blur with sharp foreground subject?

Comment: Which focal length suits your purpose? There's a lot of difference besides bokeh between a 35mm lens and a 55-200mm lens.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Which will produce a shallower depth of field: 50mm f/1.7 or 70-210mm f/4](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/74770/which-will-produce-a-shallower-depth-of-field-50mm-f-1-7-or-70-210mm-f-4) too

Answer (score 1):

35mm probably isn't well suited for Portraits as it's really wide. The DOF is nice, but I would stick with 50mm or longer for them. If you want to shoot more than 50% of the body though, 35mm would work fine.